# Visual Basic 6.0 project build issue

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “Method '~' of object '~' failed” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302026/what-does-method-of-object-failed-mean)

I am trying to build a VB 6.0 project. I have not done this for many years now and don't know what this pop up message means.

[image]

My first thought about this was that some component was missing but, I am not sure if this is what it means. Even if it does signify a missing component, how can find out which component is missing?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Subbu

Comment: Look in the project directory to see it it wrote the error to a log file.

Comment: Please Check out [this solution.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=395362)

Comment: Where does VB.NET come into this?

Comment: @raven: That link does not explain the error per se. A more general explanation would be something like that: An exception (usually SEH) occurred when calling a method/property late-bound. This can happen for various reasons -- mostly versioning with broken compatibility, but also can be a case of simple access violation or NULL pointer assignment (in a VC component).

Comment: I checked the log file created in the directory and see the following contents: a) Class SHDocVwCtl.WebBrowser of control brwWebBrowser was not a loaded control class, b) Cannot load control Inet1, c) The property name Object.TabStop in mp1 is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit the `Project` --> `References` menu and check for any references marked as missing.